# PHP random set of variables

Tags: php, variables

How would I set PHP to randomly chose between these two sets of variables to use:

```
$key = goop;
$john = heck yeah;
```

and this

```
$key = roop;
$john = reck reah;
```

Thanks ever so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using an array:

```
$selection = array(
    array('goop', 'heck yeah'),
    array('roop', 'reck reah')
);

shuffle($selection);

list($key, $john) = array_pop($selection);
```

Comment: What about the goop (first set) part? it's not included in the code you provided

Comment: How would I accomplish what you did, but with three sets?

Comment: Simply add another array into `$selection`. It'll support as many as you want to add in

Comment: Martin, but How would I make `$list` a variable? Could you also provide a working demo of the PHP code?

Comment: @SolèneLeVan `list` is a function -- it assigns the array values to the variables `$key` and `$john`

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
if ( rand(0,1) )
{
    $key = "goop";
    $john = "heck yeah";
}
else
{
    $key = "roop";
    $john = "reck reah";
}
```

Comment: But it appears that in this example the first set would get a much bigger chance, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: By far the simplest solution, `rand()` is an int, so it should be even chance

Comment: So I'd have to set the max rand() possible, like this? `rand(0, 1);` to make it equel? Or is it equel by default?

Comment: For this to work, you need to generate an integer equal to either 1 or 0 (essentially being evaluated as a boolean).

Comment: rand(0,1) would generate either 0 or 1, so it's 50% probability of returning true or false, whereas rand(0,2) would make 33% probability of returning false, ie 0, and 67% probability of returning false, ie 1 or 2

Comment: Not quite, @ribot. Your probabilities indicate that `rand()` will generate both 0 and 1 an equal number of times ;)

Comment: @BenM what would you say are the probabilities then?

Comment: How would I accomplish what you did, but with three sets?

Comment: @ribot, put it this way: the probability of `rand(0,1) == 0` is equal to `rand(0,1) == rand(0,1)`!

Comment: I'd use [mt_rand()](http://us3.php.net/mt_rand) as it is faster and should be more random.

Comment: @SolèneLeVan This is where using arrays might be better suited to your application. It is easier to extend than this sample (i.e. see my answer) :)

Comment: note that there is a fundamental difference between my answer and BenM's, because in my answer the values are always paired the same, and in BenM's they aren't. It is however easy to modify the code according to your needs.

Comment: Mine will maintain the pairs ;)

Comment: I'd love to use your code, but how would I accomplish what you did, but with three sets?

Comment: instead of doing the rand() inside the if condition: $rand = rand(0, 2); if ( $rand == 0 ) ... elseif ( $rand == 1 ) ... else

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in an array, and then use `rand()` to generate the values:

```
$key_vals = array('goop', 'roop', 'toop');
$john_vals = array('heck yeah', 'reck reah', 'leck leah');

$key = $key_vals[rand(0, (count($key_vals) - 1))];
$john = $john_vals[rand(0, (count($john_vals) - 1))];
```

You can easily extend this by adding values to the respective arrays, and increasing the maximum random number (i.e. second argument in `rand()`).

Comment: +1 Good stuff. But I'll choose ribot's as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - there's more than one way to skin a cat :)

Comment: See my updated answer on how to extend this to include more values.

Comment: How would I accomplish what you did, but with three sets?

Comment: If the pairs always have to match (i.e. `goop` with `heck yeah`) it'd be better to use Martin's answer.

Comment: both the array answers are more complicated ways to achieve the same things, which is often not worth the extra energy put into both reading and writing them

Comment: You're right, but using `if()`, `elseif()` and `else()` or a `switch()` statement isn't great, since you're going to end up with lots of extra bytes in the filesize.

Comment: @ribot wow! don't attack other's people answer! we all love reputation, but we don't have to be so feisty about it! `not worth the extra energy put into both reading and writing them` wow!

Comment: @SolèneLeVan I didn't attack any answers. Just saying that making code more complicated than it needs to be takes more energy both while writing that code and then later when reading it. It's an important aspect of efficiency in programming. It isn't necessarily like that in your case, which is why I wrote "often".

Comment: @ribot I don't consider this a complicated question and such they're all simple answers. But with multiple sets yours would certainly get ugly ;)

Comment: @Martin your answer would certainly be neater to read if there were many sets. However, using simplicity is good regardless of the complexity of the question. The question obviously doesn't cover the whole program. When one is debugging and has to go through many steps every detail matters. As such it is good practice to have extremely clear code. It will save time and energy every time one debugs.